# Polish language in Schindler's List

Tags: dialogue, schindlers-list

In the movie "Schindler's List" people are talking mostly in English and German. Since the movie is about Jews and Germans in Poland, they should talk in Yiddish/Polish and German.

I can understand that they did not want to use historically/geographically correct languages (this is common in many films) and they switched to English and German.

However, every now and then you can hear a Polish word, which sounds off - why have they decided to use this language?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[As per Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schindler%27s_List#Filming):

> Spielberg occasionally used German and Polish language in scenes to
>   recreate the feeling of being present in the past. He initially
>   considered making the film entirely in those languages, but decided
>   "there's too much safety in reading. It would have been an excuse to
>   take their eyes off the screen and watch something else."

The quote originates from [this interview with Susan Royal for *Inside Film*](http://www.insidefilm.com/spielberg2.html):

> **Susan Royal:** Originally you wanted to shoot it in Polish and German and use
>   subtitles. You didn't do that but you use a certain amount of German
>   and Polish in the film.
>
> **Steven Spielberg:** **I had Germans speaking German and Poles speaking Polish only on
>   certain occasions when I wanted to pretty much show what it was like
>   and what it sounded like** and then only let those moments come across
>   in English where I had to make a point.
>
> **Susan Royal:** Now that you see it, do you think that was a better decision than
>   going with subtitles?
>
> **Steven Spielberg:** Yeah, I think so. Because **I wanted people to watch the images, not
>   read the subtitles. There's too much safety in reading. It would have
>   been an excuse to take their eyes off the screen and watch something
>   else.**